# Unable to call the function in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
j=pd.read_excel('train1.xls', 'sheet1', na_values=['NA', '?'],header=None)
j.columns=['News','Sentiment']
train = [(j.News,j.Sentiment)]
cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(train)
```

Getting TypeError: basic_extractor() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
But while using the following code I am not getting any error:-

```
train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
    ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
    ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
    ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
    ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
    ("My boss is horrible.", "neg")
 ]
cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(train)
```

This time it is working. Do you know the what's the problem in the first case?

Comment: Please make some minimal effort to debug the issue yourself.

Comment: `train = j[["News","Sentiment"]]`

Comment: You should print the `train` and inspect very closely whats the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `zip`:

```
#for python 2 omit list
train = list(zip(j.News,j.Sentiment))
```

Sample:

```
a = train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
    ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
    ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
    ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
    ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
    ("My boss is horrible.", "neg")
 ]
j = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['News','Sentiment'])
print (j)
                                  News Sentiment
0                I love this sandwich.       pos
1            This is an amazing place!       pos
2  I feel very good about these beers.       pos
3        I do not like this restaurant       neg
4            I am tired of this stuff.       neg
5               I can't deal with this       neg
6                 My boss is horrible.       neg
```

---

```
train = list(zip(j.News,j.Sentiment))
print (train)
[('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'), ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'), ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'), ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'), ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'), ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'), ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')]
```

Comment: While using your code, I am getting a tuple type list and when I am calling this I am getting TypeError: basic_extractor() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I don't think their is any problem with my data.

Comment: I dont understand, in your question last paragraph works? `train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
    ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
    ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
    ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
    ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
    ("My boss is horrible.", "neg")
 ]
cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(train)` ?

Comment: Or do you need `cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(j[["News","Sentiment"]])` ?

Comment: Yes, even I don't know what's wrong with it.
I am trying to use this [api](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#module-textblob.en.sentiments) with my training data.

Comment: OK, give me some time, I try test it.

Comment: While using this 'cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(j[["News","Sentiment"]])' I am getting too many values to unpack error.

Comment: And this `cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(j["News"],j["Sentiment"])` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147887/discussion-between-vic13-and-jezrael).